# String array wordcount

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having some difficulties with counting letters in each word in a string array. Can anyone give me some tips? Maybe i could also use integer to string method?

```
    String s="Here is just an example"
```

should give out something like

```
       Here-4
       is-2
       just-4
```

---

```
 private static String[][] length(String[] array) {
    int counter=0;
    String [][] array=new String[array.length][array.length];
    String s="";

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            ++counter;
        }

      for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
       array[i][j]=array[counter][counter]
        }
    }

        return array;

}
```

Comment: you're looping over an empty string. `String s = ""`.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")).stream().forEach(word -> System.out.println(word + " : " + word.length()));`

Comment: is this what are u looking 
`String s="Here is just an example";
            String[] splitString = s.split(" ");
            for(int i=0 ; i<splitString.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("splitString[i].length();   "+splitString[i].length());
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "Here is just an example"
Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+").stream().forEach(word -> System.out.println(word + ": " + word.length()));
```

This splits your `s` on spaces and puts it into a list. Then it iterates over each word in the list and print both the word and the length of the word.

Comment: thank you but im trying to do it without inbuilt functions as split and Arrays.asList

Comment: i already have another method which splits it without the inbuilt functions

Comment: Ok. So you just need to count each word in the array that's passed in?

Answer (score 1):

Use java tokenizer,

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("Here is just an example");
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
         String tmp = st.nextToken();
         System.out.println(tmp.length()); // this would print the length

     }
```

It is available since JDK.1.0

Comment: thank you but im trying to do it without tokenizer and scanner :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to think about when trying to solve a problem like this:

- How do I split up each word?
- How do I count the length of each word?

I'd solve this problem by splitting it up into two problems as I describe above.

First - splitting the `String` can be accomplished by using `String#split`.  It accepts a regular expression, but you can use most characters to help build that expression out. In this case, we'll use a special character to help us catch all whitespace characters - notably, `"\\s+"`.

```
// Assuming s is defined
String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
```

Now that you have a split, you can iterate over that array and get the length of each.  Strings have a `.length()` method attached to them so you can get the length without having to count individual characters.

```
for(String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word + ": " + word.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s="Here is just an example";

        //first you have to break the sentence to words
        String stringArray[] = s.split("\\s");

        //then iterate each word and get the length of the word.
        for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(stringArray[i] +" - "+stringArray[i].length());
        }
    }
}
```

hope this will help.

**Output:**

Here - 4

is - 2

just - 4

an - 2

example - 7

Comment: read the comments, for some reason they don't want to use builtin functions

Comment: I'm wonder why this answer got minus since the answer which is accept also contains same thing.

Answer (score -2):

In your provided code, you have a `String[] array` passed in as an argument, then you define a new `String[][] array`. You shouldn't do that. I'm assuming since you said you already have a function that splits the string, then the `String[] array` argument is that array. If so, try this. Also, is there a reason you're trying to do it without the built in functions? We developers usually don't like to reinvent the wheel unless there's a good reason to do so.

```
 private static String[][] length(String[] array) {
    String[] anotherArray = new String[array.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        anotherArray[i] = array[i] + ": " array[i].length;
    }
    return array;
}
```